# Check process of detached Docker exec command

Tags: docker

I have a python script that loads my db with a bunch of data and thus takes a long while for it to run. Because of this if I run...

```
$ docker exec -d CONTAINER python /path/to/myscript.py
```

Was curious if it is possible to run

```
$ docker exec -it CONTAINER /bin/bash
$ root@container-hash /# ps -ax
```

And see if that process is still running?

Comment: Should be possible, but why not some log statements about the progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to your docker container via `exec` as long as the python script has not finished yet. When it is done, the container will be stopped and you can't connect any more.

As long as it is running, you can use `docker logs CONTAINER` to show the output of your container, if any.

Comment: So does Docker exec boot another container next to one that is already running? The container in question has my flask app running.

Comment: No, docker exec connects to the running container and does not create a new one. You can connect to it, check it, change the content and verify that everything is running as you expect it.